# using diff and cumsum in R

Tags: r, data.table, diff, cumsum

I have been trying to use a solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831682/subset-where-there-are-at-least-five-consecutive-years-in-a-data-frame-column), however it is not working for some reason.

Basically, i want to find all IDs that have at least 4 **consecutive** years and only keep rows that belong to those IDs.

Any ideas?

```
# example data
ID <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 2), rep("D", 3), rep("E", 4))
year <- as.numeric(c(rep(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 4), 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016))
mydata <- cbind(ID, year)
mydata <- as.data.table(mydata)
mydata$year <- as.numeric(mydata$year)

# provided solution
mydata2 <- setDT(mydata)[, grp := cumsum(c(0, diff(year)) > 1), by = ID
                         ][, if (.N > 4) .SD, by = grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

Comment: Do you want the solution to use `data.table`?

Comment: [This solution from @Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831711/10442423) seems to work with your data. I tested it with the "compact" version at the bottom.

Comment: i think the chosen solution in the linked post is missing another grouping variable in the 2nd `[`. You will need `setDT(mydata)[, grp := cumsum(c(0, diff(year))!=1L), ID][, 
    if (.N >= 4) .SD, .(ID, grp)]` or in one `[`: `mydata[mydata[, if (.N >= 4L) .I, .(ID, cumsum(c(0L, diff(year)!=1L)))]$V1]` and `mydata <- data.table(ID, year)` will work just fine without `cbind` and then `as.numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do that with `data.table`. Basically, you want to make sure to have the table sorted first. Second, I'm using `diff(year)==1`. We want consecutive years, so it's important that the `diff` is exactly equal to 1 to prevent jumps in years. Finally, I'm only keeping IDs that have a max(cumsum) of 3 or more (3 not 4 since we are starting to count from 0).

```
setorder(mydata)
mydata2 <- mydata[, grp := cumsum(c(0, diff(year)==1)), by = ID]
mydata2[,max_grp := max(grp), by=ID]
mydata2[max_grp>=3]

    ID year grp max_grp
 1:  A 2012   0       3
 2:  A 2012   0       3
 3:  A 2013   1       3
 4:  A 2014   2       3
 5:  A 2015   3       3
 6:  B 2012   0       3
 7:  B 2013   1       3
 8:  B 2013   1       3
 9:  B 2014   2       3
10:  B 2014   2       3
11:  B 2015   3       3
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for... the only thing is that what if i would like to keep only the last 3 years, also for IDs that have 4+ years? How can that be done? aka for 4 years data, discarding 0, for 5 years discarding 0 and 1 and so on.

Comment: i tried mydata2 <- mydata2[which(year >= max(year - K)), by = ID] but get an error